# json_decode with JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING and object_get_vars, can't access array key

Tags: php, json

I have this piece of code:

```
$test = json_decode('{"1229410050415660":"This works just fine","87402531":"This does not"}', false, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);

echo $test->{87402531}; // works

$test = get_object_vars($test);   

echo $test[1229410050415660]; //doesn't work
echo $test["1229410050415660"]; // works!!   

echo $test[87402531]; //doesn't work
echo $test["87402531"]; //doesn't work either

$test[87402531] = 'This should work now.';

echo $test[87402531]; //works
echo $test["87402531"]; //also works

var_dump($test);
```

This is the output:

```
This does not

Notice: Undefined offset: 1431739436 in ... on line ...

This works just fine

Notice: Undefined offset: 87402531 in ... on line ...

Notice: Undefined offset: 87402531 in ... on line ...

This should work now.
This should work now.
```

And this is the var dump:

```
array(3) {
  ["1229410050415660"]=>
    string(20) "This works just fine"
  ["87402531"]=>
    string(13) "This does not"
  [87402531]=>
    string(21) "This should work now."
}
```

This works all the time.

```
echo $test[1229410050415660];
```

How can i avoid this, or how can i get "This does not" from the array?

I'm using PHP 7.0.14.

Thank you!

Comment: Your code works just fine for me (php5.6 though), though in general it's not recommended to use integers as object keys as you'll get all kind of weird edge cases. Why not decode the json directly to an associative array with `json_decode(..., true)`?

Comment: Yes, but if i have a large number as a value in an array, json decodes in a scientific format. For eg. 1229410050415660 will become 1.2294100504157E+15, that's why i'm using JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING

Comment: Yes the JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING parameter is fine. What I mean is the second parameter should be `true` so that you get an associative array right away. i.e. `json_decode('...', true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);`